# My reputation has changed in a strange manner

Tags: bug, reputation

I have one response today on Stack Overflow with 4 up votes. However, my reputation changed with +38. There was another question that was strongly disliked, but I answered. I can no longer find this question anymore (it is not listed in my "answers" tab), but when I last checked my answer was not downvoted in fact I believe my answer was not bad). Also, when I check my reputation change, only +40 is listed.

Any ideas what happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you got one downvote on the answer you posted on the now deleted question.

Due to recent changes we can now see those things:

1. Go to [your reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812912/izomorphius?tab=reputation).
2. Tick the "show removed posts" checkbox in the bottom of the page, so it's marked.
3. If the page won't auto reload, reload it.

You should now see the "+2" reputation change. (As you have less than 10K reputation probably without a link)

Comment: This still does not explain why the summary on the tab is incorrect.

Comment: @Oded might be a bug, not updating that piece of information wherever it's being stored. My answer was to help the OP understand what happened and possibly see what question got deleted.

Comment: Yep, just adding more info... I do believe this is a bug on that bit of display (I have seen it myself on my profile).

Answer (score 2):

The reputation highlight on the profile page seems to not take account of reputation gains on removed questions/answers.

This means that if you had a single downvote on a question/answer that was deleted and 4 upvotes on an answer, you will see on the highlight +38, though everywhere else you will see 40.

Take a look at the [reputation audit page](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) to see what the system believes happened (votes on deleted posts do not appear).

Comment: I can not seem to find myself on the page you link to.

Comment: @izomorphius - That page is **your** reputation audit. It is all about you...

Comment: FYI the `/reputaion` [is now obsolete](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes#comment331489_124059) and will be removed sooner or later.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - Not sure what you linked to there. The way I read the comment it means that recalcs will be obsolete.

Comment: @Oded sorry my bad - misread the comment. Still, with the new reputation history in the profile it's much easier to see it all in the profile rather in the "raw view" of the reputation audit page.